# How to ensure the order of list shown in UITableView when getting data for cell from UIDocument

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uidocument

My app fetches data via FileManager for each cell in UITableView. The cells need data from a file which requires open UIDocument objects. However, it seems like code inside open completion handler get executed non predictably, so the cells don't get displayed in the order I wish.

How do I solve this problem? I appreciate if anyone gives any clue.

```swift
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(true)
   fetchCellsData()
}

func fetchCellsData() {

    do {
        let files = getUrlsOfFiles()    //files in a certain order
        for file in files {

            let document = MyDocument(fileURL: file) //MyDocument subclassing UIDocument

            //open to get data for cell
            document.open { (success) in
                if !success {
                    print("File not open at %@", file)
                    return
                }

                let data = populateCellData(document.fileInfo)

                self.cellsData.append(data)
                self.tableView.reloadData()

                /// tried below also
                //  DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //    self.cellsData.append(data)
                //    self.tableView.reloadData()
                //  }
            }
            document.close(completionHandler: nil)
        }

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! MyCell
    let fileInfo = cellsData[indexPath.row].fileInfo
    //assign fileInfo into MyCell property
    return cell
}
```

I expect cells get rendered in the order of 'files', however, it seems like the order is a bit unpredictable presuming that it's due to the fact that 'cellForRowAt' gets called before it knows about the full set of 'cellsData'.

Comment: can you share the `getUrlsOfFiles()` func?

Comment: Call fetchCellsData() in viewDidLoad().

Comment: @manishsharma93 wont solve the problem though. Maybe hide it if he has a feu files to open but thats all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apple documentation on `UIdocument` . [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocument/1619977-open):

> open(completionHandler:)
>
> Opens a document asynchronously.

Which means that even if you trigger `document.open` in the right order, nothing guarantees that the `completionHandler` sequence will be in the same order, this is why the order is *unpredictible*.

However, you know that they will **eventually** all get done.

What you could do is :

1 - place all your datas from opened document into another list

2 - `order` this list in accordance to your need

3 - place this list into `cellsData` (which I assume is bound to your tableViesDatasource)

```swift
var allDatas: [/*your data type*/] = []

...

    do {
        // reset allDatas 
        allDatas = []
        let files = getUrlsOfFiles()

        for file in files {

            let document = MyDocument(fileURL: file) 
            document.open { (success) in
                if !success {
                    print("File not open at %@", file)
                    return
                }

                let data = populateCellData(document.fileInfo)

                self.allDatas.append(data) // "buffer" list
                self.tableView.reloadData()  
            }
            document.close(completionHandler: nil)
        }

    } catch { ...
```

Then you change `cellsData` to a computed property like so :

```
var cellsData: [/*your data type*/] {
   get {
      return allDatas.order( /* order in accordance to your needs */ )
   }
}
```

this way, each time a new data is added, the list is orderer before being redisplayed.

---

**Discussion**

this is the **easier** solution regarding the state of your code, however this may not be the overall prefered solution. For instance in your code, you reload your tableview **each time** you add a new value, knowing that there will be more data added after, which is not optimised.

I suggest you to read on **Dispatch Group**, this is a way to wait until all asynchronous operation your triggered are finished before executing certain actions (such as reloading your tableview in this case) (Readings: [Raywenderlich tuts](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5371-grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-for-swift-4-part-2-2))

Comment: Good solution and good suggestion. raywenderlich tutorial for DispatchGroup is also very helpful. I appreciate it!